# Rotate back div after the second click on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I used CSS and Javascript in order to rotate a div after a click on it (from 0deg to 45deg). It's working good. I want the div to rotate back after a second click on it (from 45deg to 0deg), but nothing happens on the div... I didn't find more topics to fix this problem.
If you have any idea, it would be great ! Thanks.

*Style*

```
.home {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
    transition-property: transform;
}


.home.active {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(45deg);
}
```

*Script*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.home').click(function(){
        $('.home').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `toggleClass`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.home').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

CSS3 can accomplish the transformation, See [Firefox MDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) for more info

**HTML**

```
<div class="description-wrapper">
    <div class="category-desc-toggle rotate redbg"></div>
    <div class="category-desc">REEED!</div>
</div>

<div class="description-wrapper">
    <div class="category-desc-toggle bluebg rotate"></div>
    <div class="category-desc">Blue</div>
</div>

<div class="description-wrapper">
    <div class="category-desc-toggle yellowbg rotate"></div>
    <div class="category-desc">Yellow Box</div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
 $(".description-wrapper").click(function() {
    $(this).children('div.category-desc').slideToggle(300);
    $(this).children('div.category-desc-toggle').toggleClass("rotate45");
});
```

**CSS**

```
.description-wrapper {
    width: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.redbg {
    background-color: red;
}

.bluebg {
    background-color: blue;
}

.yellowbg {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.rotate { 
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); 
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); 
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.rotate45 { 
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); 
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.category-desc-toggle { 
    width: 80px;
    height: 75px; 

    -moz-transition: all .3s; 
    -webkit-transition: all .3s; 
    -o-transition: all .3s; 
    transition: all .3s; 
}
```

### [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Gagan_Gami/7K6GP/13/)